# Xtend picks the wrong overload

Tags: spring, xtend

I'm playing with Xtend, and have hit a roadblock.

My class uses a Spring Data repository.  Here's the interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<UserNode>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<UserNode> {
        public UserNode findByEntityId(Long entityId);
}
```

the super interface of `GraphRepository<T>` (which is [part of Spring Data](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/repository/CRUDRepository.html), not my project) declares the following:

```
@Transactional
<U extends T> U save(U entity);

@Transactional
<U extends T> Iterable<U> save(Iterable<U> entities);
```

However, the following code fails for me:

```
// UpdateUserProcessorExample.xtend
class UpdateUserProcessorExample {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository

    def updateUser()
    {
        var user = repository.findByEntityId(1L)
        // The following line generates an error:
        repository.save(user)
    }
}
```

This generates:

> Bounds mismatch: The type argument  is not a valid substitute for
>   the bounded type parameter  of the method
>   save(Iterable)

It appears as though Xtend is picking the wrong overloaded method.

I've tried adding type hints, ala:

```
var UserNode user = repository.findByEntityId(1L)
```

But this still generates the same error.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

On the Xtend mailing list, Sven advised he's raised a bug for this issue:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413138

He also offered the following work-around:

> A not so nice solution is to override the respective methods in
>   UserRepository and replace T by UserNode, like this :

```
public interface UserRepo extends GraphRepository<UserNode> {
    UserNode findByEntityId(Long entityId);

    @Override UserNode save(UserNode entity);

    @Override <U extends UserNode> Iterable<? extends U> save(Iterable<? extends U> entities);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have introduced additional type parameters on the methods, can't you you just use the one from the class level?

```
@Transactional
T save(T entity);

@Transactional
Iterable<? extends T> save(Iterable<? extends T> entities);
```

That should work.

Comment: `GraphRepository`, which declares the methods you mention, is part of Spring Data, not my project.  (Apologies if that wasn't clear).